# PHP docstring @return type for subclass of current class

Tags: php

What is the canonical `@return` type for a static method of a parent class that returns an instance of a subclass, undetermined at time of writing? For example:

```
<?php

    class Thing {

        /**
         * Do something
         *
         * @return ???  Instance of some new class.
         */
        public static function create_subclass($class) {
            return new $class();
        }

    }

    class Person extends Thing {}

    $person = Thing::create_subclass('Person');

?>
```

It seems like this shouldn't be `@return self` because it's returning a subclass of `self`, and specifying all possible return classes would be silly. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to have a parent class that creates new instances of its children?

Comment: @MichaelLeaCrawford Because a static constructor wants to decide which subclass to instantiate based upon the arguments it receives. SourceMaking [suggests some motives](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-constructor-with-factory-method) for this. Over in Objective-C, Apple's libraries go all the way with this idea with [*class clusters*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) - whenever you construct, say, an `NSString`, `NSArray` or `NSDate`, you *actually* invisibly get given an instance of a private subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@return Thing` or `@return Person|AnotherClass|AnotherClass`

Comment: Agree to @return Thing